# How to get the value of a checkbox using getelementbyID inside a form

Tags: javascript

I have a code which worked fine while I was testing it now I decided it to include it inside a form and it just does not want to work. If I remove the form tag it works and with the form tag it does not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script>
function action() {
var checkBox = document.getElementById("UPCheck");
if (checkBox.checked == true){
    window.localStorage['username'] = document.getElementById('username').value;
    window.localStorage['password'] = document.getElementById('password').value;
    window.localStorage['unpwchecked'] = "yes";
    alert("Saved!");
}
else
{
    window.localStorage['username'] = "";
    window.localStorage['password'] = "";
    window.localStorage['unpwchecked'] = "";
}
}
function action2() {
    document.getElementById('username').value = window.localStorage['username'];
    document.getElementById('password').value = window.localStorage['password'];
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="">
<input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="">
Save username / password in cookies: <input type="checkbox" id="UPCheck" name="savelocalunpw">
<p><button onclick="action()" type="button">Save values!</button></p>
<p><button onclick="action2()" type="button">Load values!</button></p>
</form>
<script>
var alerted = localStorage.getItem('unpwchecked');
if (alerted == 'yes') {
document.getElementById('username').value = window.localStorage['username'];
document.getElementById('password').value = window.localStorage['password'];
document.getElementById("UPCheck").checked = true;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Remove the form tag and values are properly saved in localstorage.

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the function name. If you rename

```
function action()
```

to

```
function action1()
```

and also modify

```
<button onclick="action1()" type="button">Save values!</button>
```

then your code will work.

I notices that without the form tag, the code works ok. If you add the form element, then you will get a console error, stating that `action()` is not a function. I'm just guessing that there is a conflict between the function name `action()` and the form attribute `action`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var isChecked = document.getElementById("UPCheck").checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably better practice to add an event handler for the buttons, that works with the form tags.  Kind of interesting that it works with renaming the function.

JS

```
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function(){

var checkBox = document.getElementById("UPCheck");
if (checkBox.checked == true){
    window.localStorage.username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    window.localStorage.password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    window.localStorage.unpwchecked = "yes";
    alert("Saved!");
}
else
{
    window.localStorage.username = "";
    window.localStorage.password = "";
    window.localStorage.unpwchecked = "";
}
});

document.getElementById("load").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById('username').value = window.localStorage.username;
    document.getElementById('password').value = window.localStorage.password;
});

var alerted = localStorage.getItem('unpwchecked');
if (alerted == 'yes') {
document.getElementById('username').value = window.localStorage.username;
document.getElementById('password').value = window.localStorage.password;
document.getElementById("UPCheck").checked = true;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>

</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="">
<input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="">
Save username / password in cookies: <input type="checkbox" id="UPCheck" name="savelocalunpw">
<p><button  id = "save" type="button">Save values!</button></p>
<p><button  id = "load" type="button">Load values!</button></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

You can use "dot" notation for localStorage.